# how to create a custom asynchronous function in node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, asynchronous

Ii'm trying to do something like.

```js
function fun1(){
  for(var j=0;j<20;j++)
  {
    var n = j;
    console.log("i= "+n);
  }
}
function fun2()
{
  console.log("In Callback");
}  

fun1();
fun2();
```

its working fine till now and got output as expected.

But, I want to call function `fun1()` and `fun2()` asynchronously it means `fun2()` call before `fun1()`, b'coz `fun1()` will take some time for complete the execution as compare to `fun2()`.

How can I achieve this, Node.js provide asynchronous function, Is it already defined function can asynchronous only or we can make them according our need.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are asking, but i think what you are looking is control flow. For that, take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/async or even better with promises and generators. https://gist.github.com/swarajgiri/16202e32aa4d80d45c62

Answer (score 9):

There are multiple ways to achieve this in JavaScript (not node-specific, but there are modules that make your life easier):

---

#### callbacks

They are somewhat [continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) and it is a shame developers were bothered with handling them manually (compilers used to do that themselves). But they work:

```js
function callee(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback(null, 'finished!');
  }, 2000);
}

function caller() {
  document.write('started!');
  callee(function(err, result) {
    document.write(result);
  });
}

caller();
```

It is common in the node environment to indicate errors with the first parameter of the callback (like `callback(new Error("something wrong!"))`).

---

#### promises

As callbacks get ugly when nested (imagine 10-20 of them, you'd be screwed debugging this), the idea of [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) came up. You might know them as [Futures](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) from java. They are built-in to ES6, and you can use them beforehand in the node environment with [`npm i promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise) -- many client-side frameworks (e.g. jQuery, AngularJS) have their own implementations. Originally there was [Q](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/).

```js
var Promise = require('promise');

function callee() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve('finished!');
    }, 1000);
  });
}

function caller() {
  document.write('started!');
  callee().then(function(result) {
    document.write(result);
  });
}

caller();
```

---

#### generators

ES6 has [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*). You might know them from [python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

They provide asynchronity as well, as they `yield` new values once they are computed.

I recommend reading [Learn ES2015](http://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#generators) for more information on that.

*My personal opinion is to never ever use generators as they interfere heavily with promises and make debugging really hard.*

---

#### async/await

ES7 will make life a whole lot easier with `async`/`await`. You can basically say that a function will be performed asynchronously and that you want to await a result (once you are in a async function). [ES7 async functions](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/es7-async-functions/) is a good start to read on that. It's like

```js
async function callee() {
  return (() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve('finished!'), 1000);
    })
  })();
}

async function caller() {
  document.write('started!');
  document.write(await callee());
}

// the global async wrapper
(async function() {
  caller();
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to provide a better version of [@Dominik Schreiber's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32198265/2404470)

```js
async function callee() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('finished!'), 1000);
  })
}

async function caller() {
  console.log('started!');
  console.log(await callee());
}

caller();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a callback to the event que with

```
 process.nextTick(callback);
```

Don't do that, it is almost never what you want.
JavaScript is single threaded so adding a callback still blocks the call of f2.
If you have a function that takes a long time to run run it in a child_process or even better, create a separate micro service for it.